# SSL not working with http-kit but working with plain Java

Tags: java, ssl, clojure, iis-7

I'm having a problem sending request to an web server that's running IIS7 using http-kit. What I see, when I turn debugging mode, is that right after sending the get request, I get, apparently, a couple of small packages and a bunch of "Ignoring unsupported cipher suite:" followed by a timeout:

```
%% Cached client session: [Session-22, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C A4 24 50 40   A5 F2 3B DD 01 BB 7C A2  .....$P@..;.....
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 208
0000: 47 45 54 20 2F ## ## ##   ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##  GET /###########
0010: ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##   ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##  ################
0020: ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##   ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##  ################
0030: ## ## ## ## ## ## ## 20   48 54 54 50 2F 31 2E 31  ####### HTTP/1.1
0040: 0D 0A 48 6F 73 74 3A 20   ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##  ..Host: ########
0050: ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##   ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##  ################
0060: ## ## ## ## ## 0D 0A 55   73 65 72 2D 41 67 65 6E  #####..User-Agen
0070: 74 3A 20 68 74 74 70 2D   6B 69 74 2F 32 2E 30 0D  t: http-kit/2.0.
0080: 0A 41 63 63 65 70 74 2D   45 6E 63 6F 64 69 6E 67  .Accept-Encoding
0090: 3A 20 67 7A 69 70 2C 20   64 65 66 6C 61 74 65 0D  : gzip, deflate.
00A0: 0A 43 6F 6E 74 65 6E 74   2D 4C 65 6E 67 74 68 3A  .Content-Length:
00B0: 20 30 0D 0A 0D 0A AF DD   9B 8A C3 9A BB BE 20 8B   0............ .
00C0: 94 AB 63 0F 74 80 4D 59   F4 73 05 05 05 05 05 05  ..c.t.MY.s......
client-loop, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 182
[Raw write (bb)]: length = 213
0000: 17 03 01 00 D0 92 D5 AB   1C 3E 93 5F 45 C1 30 0D  .........>._E.0.
0010: 25 6A 5F E7 67 06 2B 2B   2A B4 1E E5 7E EE 6C 96  %j_.g.++*.....l.
0020: F5 A6 D0 19 37 3E 30 9D   99 6B 8F 75 E3 35 16 02  ....7>0..k.u.5..
0030: 90 4E 6D 22 A5 FE FF 37   E9 DF 7C 38 25 4B 05 6D  .Nm"...7...8%K.m
0040: CC 0A 8E 0E 3A 43 44 1F   23 83 D6 C4 4E B5 55 45  ....:CD.#...N.UE
0050: 58 7B 53 6E 03 2B 73 08   E6 EB 1E 49 75 B9 6E B4  X.Sn.+s....Iu.n.
0060: 2F 7D 6F 9A B2 B9 15 90   5F C7 82 67 98 39 AE 07  /.o....._..g.9..
0070: DC D0 53 B7 6C C2 C3 BE   7F 40 3F 73 DF 56 8A 3B  ..S.l....@?s.V.;
0080: D2 A2 EF F7 16 AC 4E F9   4C 75 F8 B1 A6 3B 95 F6  ......N.Lu...;..
0090: 92 73 AF 84 C0 52 6A 08   77 8C A7 B1 18 A4 71 B7  .s...Rj.w.....q.
00A0: B6 8C 56 19 7A A1 12 6C   E6 94 B0 84 C1 40 89 6D  ..V.z..l.....@.m
00B0: B7 D5 8C F5 57 80 3E 19   2D 11 24 B3 88 A2 F5 9C  ....W.>.-.$.....
00C0: FA 38 F9 D7 E8 1F 7B 7E   9F 72 68 BF 8C 82 D6 1E  .8.......rh.....
00D0: B7 3D 33 06 98                                     .=3..
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 01 00 20                                     ....
[Raw read]: length = 32
0000: AA AA D1 B2 BE D1 00 84   C1 93 BF 8A 9A 77 ED 76  .............w.v
0010: 53 BB E0 3B 4B DB E6 A6   92 00 D0 2E 05 B7 4F EF  S..;K.........O.
client-loop, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 32
Padded plaintext after DECRYPTION:  len = 32
0000: 00 00 00 00 C5 5C 82 7D   4D E6 C8 3D F5 2D F6 9F  .....\..M..=.-..
0010: 64 B6 F9 DF 53 90 99 3F   07 07 07 07 07 07 07 07  d...S..?........
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: false
Is secure renegotiation: true
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
=>
{:opts {:sslengine #object[sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl
                           0x7a21e0f7
                           "7a21e0f7[SSLEngine[hostname=null port=-1] TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]"],
        :timeout 4000,
        :method :get,
        :url "https://################################################################################"},
 :error #error{:cause "read timeout: 4000ms",
               :via [{:type org.httpkit.client.TimeoutException,
                      :message "read timeout: 4000ms",
                      :at [org.httpkit.client.HttpClient clearTimeout "HttpClient.java" 82]}],
               :trace [[org.httpkit.client.HttpClient clearTimeout "HttpClient.java" 82]
                       [org.httpkit.client.HttpClient run "HttpClient.java" 433]
                       [java.lang.Thread run "Thread.java" 745]]}}
```

The code that makes this happen looks like this:

```
@(org.httpkit.client/get "https://################################################################################"
                         {:sslengine (build-ssl-engine (build-ssl-context {:keystore    "####################" :keystore-pass "########"
                                                                           :trust-store "####################" :trust-store-pass "########"
                                                                           :protocol    "TLSv1"}))
                          :timeout   4000})
```

The helper functions are:

```
(defn- setup-keystore ^KeyStore [file ^String password]
  (let [keystore (KeyStore/getInstance "JKS")]
    (with-open [inputstream (io/input-stream (io/resource file))]
      (.load keystore inputstream (.toCharArray password)))
    keystore))

(defn- key-managers [file ^String password]
  (let [manager-factory (KeyManagerFactory/getInstance (KeyManagerFactory/getDefaultAlgorithm))]
    (.init manager-factory (setup-keystore file password) (.toCharArray password))
    (.getKeyManagers manager-factory)))

(defn- trust-managers [file password]
  (let [manager-factory (TrustManagerFactory/getInstance (TrustManagerFactory/getDefaultAlgorithm))]
    (.init manager-factory (setup-keystore file password))
    (.getTrustManagers manager-factory)))

(defn build-ssl-context ^javax.net.ssl.SSLContext [{:keys [trust-store trust-store-pass keystore keystore-pass protocol]
                                                    :or   {protocol "TLS"}}]
  (let [key-managers (key-managers keystore keystore-pass)
        trust-managers (trust-managers trust-store trust-store-pass)
        ssl-context (SSLContext/getInstance protocol)]
    (.init ssl-context key-managers trust-managers nil)
    (SSLContext/setDefault ssl-context)
    ssl-context))

(defn build-ssl-engine [^SSLContext ssl-context]
  (doto (.createSSLEngine ssl-context)
    (.setUseClientMode true)
    (.setNeedClientAuth true)))
```

Now, I have a piece of Java code that is similar but works.

```
%% Cached client session: [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C D2 53 C9 75   95 CC 0C E5 48 44 0E 7C  .....S.u....HD..
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 240
0000: 47 45 54 20 ## ## ## ##   ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##  GET /###########
0010: ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##   ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##  ################
0020: ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##   ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##  ################
0030: ## ## ## ## ## ## ## 20   48 54 54 50 2F 31 2E 31  ####### HTTP/1.1
0040: 0D 0A 55 73 65 72 2D 41   67 65 6E 74 3A 20 4A 61  ..User-Agent: Ja
0050: 76 61 2F 31 2E 38 2E 30   5F 31 31 32 0D 0A 48 6F  va/1.8.0_112..Ho
0060: 73 74 3A 20 ## ## ## ##   ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##   st: ############
0070: ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##   ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##  ################
0080: ## 0D 0A 41 63 63 65 70   74 3A 20 74 65 78 74 2F  #..Accept: text/
0090: 68 74 6D 6C 2C 20 69 6D   61 67 65 2F 67 69 66 2C  html, image/gif,
00A0: 20 69 6D 61 67 65 2F 6A   70 65 67 2C 20 2A 3B 20   image/jpeg, *;
00B0: 71 3D 2E 32 2C 20 2A 2F   2A 3B 20 71 3D 2E 32 0D  q=.2, */*; q=.2.
00C0: 0A 43 6F 6E 6E 65 63 74   69 6F 6E 3A 20 6B 65 65  .Connection: kee
00D0: 70 2D 61 6C 69 76 65 0D   0A 0D 0A 82 2E C5 FA E3  p-alive.........
00E0: B7 BC 64 D0 AE 36 F6 FE   0A E7 38 D3 0A 39 76 00  ..d..6....8..9v.
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 240
[Raw write]: length = 245
0000: 17 03 01 00 F0 34 28 EC   E7 31 92 96 43 E2 36 83  .....4(..1..C.6.
0010: AA 59 C1 CD EC 08 0D 8F   02 F0 3B 9D 3C 0A 65 73  .Y........;.<.es
0020: E7 FF 7E 08 5A 39 F2 16   AB 7F 02 CF B3 E4 A3 14  ....Z9..........
0030: 46 A4 EC 5A 1C B2 81 7B   CA 65 78 5E DF 19 48 40  F..Z.....ex^..H@
0040: 2F 2B 0F D4 BB 6D 09 52   C6 14 BC C8 D2 C5 41 8A  /+...m.R......A.
0050: 91 5F 90 53 A9 E3 15 21   2E 7C 8E 7B 2B E5 46 D6  ._.S...!....+.F.
0060: 9A 32 8F DF 35 49 6C 9A   DA CB 02 BA BE 83 1D D3  .2..5Il.........
0070: 39 D6 C5 F4 E9 27 E9 1D   A6 3F 0E BB C8 BE A0 6C  9....'...?.....l
0080: 32 97 BC FC 0C 04 68 8F   CC 6B DA AF F2 40 2D 56  2.....h..k...@-V
0090: 47 EC 92 F5 36 19 FF F6   B4 97 31 9F 5D F0 75 31  G...6.....1.].u1
00A0: 12 6A AD D2 FA 95 22 A5   F7 D8 20 36 D9 F9 69 87  .j...."... 6..i.
00B0: 67 05 AE 97 68 81 8D C4   38 AC 74 6A B7 DB 51 DE  g...h...8.tj..Q.
00C0: A2 65 86 F1 F4 F7 27 2C   3D 3C 85 BE DB 97 01 C7  .e....',=<......
00D0: 70 CE 19 FE D6 44 24 AE   F3 38 79 C2 B9 DE 71 EB  p....D$..8y...q.
00E0: 47 1A 3A 94 E8 3D F9 A0   DD 51 FD CE 01 84 E7 23  G.:..=...Q.....#
00F0: 8B F8 07 B2 2D                                     ....-
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 01 00 20                                     ....
[Raw read]: length = 32
0000: E6 11 77 2F 9D 87 61 F5   FE 99 0D 62 51 7E D0 93  ..w/..a....bQ...
0010: 55 D2 4B B3 E8 91 DC F6   69 D8 2E 2E BF F4 B2 0F  U.K.....i.......
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 32
Padded plaintext after DECRYPTION:  len = 32
0000: 00 00 00 00 43 53 ED 57   2D 63 29 89 E3 20 9C DD  ....CS.W-c).. ..
0010: 17 58 AA E5 3D 13 BC BB   07 07 07 07 07 07 07 07  .X..=...........
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: false
Is secure renegotiation: true
*** HelloRequest (empty)
%% Client cached [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
%% Try resuming [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA] from port 57365
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
```

The almost equilavent Java code is:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String keystore = "####################";
            String keystorePassword = "########";
            String trustStore = "####################";
            String trustStorePassword = "########";
            String protocol = "TLSv1";

            buildSslContext(keystore, keystorePassword, trustStore, trustStorePassword, protocol);

            URL url = new URL("https://################################################################################");
            HttpsURLConnection httpsCon = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpsCon.setRequestMethod("GET");
            String responseMessage = httpsCon.getResponseMessage();

            System.out.printf("Response Message is %s\n", responseMessage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void buildSslContext(String keystore, String keystorePassword, String trustStore, String trustStorePassword, String protocol) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, IOException, CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(protocol);
        KeyManager[] keyManagers = keyManagers(keystore, keystorePassword);
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagers(trustStore, trustStorePassword);
        sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);
        SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);
    }

    private static TrustManager[] trustManagers(String file, String password) throws KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException {
        KeyStore trustStore = setupKeystore(file, password);
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
        return trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
    }

    private static KeyManager[] keyManagers(String file, String password) throws KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        KeyStore keyStore = setupKeystore(file, password);
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, password.toCharArray());
        return keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();
    }

    private static KeyStore setupKeystore(String file, String password) throws KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException {
        InputStream trustStoreUrl = new FileInputStream(file);
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        trustStore.load(trustStoreUrl, password.toCharArray());
        return trustStore;
    }
}
```

The big difference is that the Clojure code is creating its own SSLEngine while Java code seems to work just by making the SSLContext the default one. It seems Java creates an SSLEngine from that Context while http-kit expects you to provide it. Note that I'm fixing it to TLSv1 because this IIS 7 kills the connection if I use TLSv1.1 or v1.2.

Any ideas what's going on and/or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I'll preface this with "I am not a Clojure person", but I think you are correct that you need to provide your own `SSLContext` to the `http-kit` code. There is a good [blog post here](https://www.lvh.io/posts/https-requests-with-client-certificates-in-clojure.html) which discusses how to use a Clojure library called [`less-awful-ssl`](https://github.com/aphyr/less-awful-ssl) to generate the `SSLContext` and provide it as an `opts` map to the `http-kit` request method via `(.createSSLEngine ctx)` which will give you the correct `SSLEngine`.

For the record, I've often seen (even in pure Java) the "Ignoring unsupported cipher suite" message for all nominally-supported suites when the provided keystore either doesn't have an RSA/DSA key or the certificate is not valid (i.e. dates are expired, etc.).

Comment: The context I'm generating is fine as far as u know and using less awful ssl will require massaging the keys quite a bit, but I tried less awful ssl's ssl-context->ssl-engine and I still get the same problem.